# Philosophy vs. Real Life

Tags: life

I read and listen to learn about life, existence, and consciousness. I find it comforting and interesting to realize how much I don’t know. However, in a split second, one of my children yell for me, and all is lost. Until I come back to read again hours or days later. Is there a term for that? Are there writings on how to bridge the gap? I’d like for my mind to remain aware and in awe rather than blinded by “real-life” or whatever this is that I call real life—Jobs, kids, houses, things I see, things I feel, etc.

Comment: There's an old story about the great sage who lives on the mountain top, meditates for years, understands the mysteries of the universe, then one day goes into town to a market, gets jostled by the crowd, and loses his cool. Happens to the best of us, right?

Comment: So you judge to remain awe in your mind from reading and listening to learn about life is more important than actually lives and experiences life consisting of all those aspects you mentioned and many more?...

Comment: Check out writings, blogs, video talks, etc about Nonduality. Equanimity gets better, but if you need to respond to something, of course you will.

Comment: You might also find that meditation helps you learn how to stay 'with' your awareness through changing situations. I read one meditation teacher who said that if you get lost in thought during practice, trace back through your train of thought to the point where you diverged from the meditation technique. He said, "If you can't trace all the way back, you're really lost." Strong words, but meant to inspire diligence. I often try to recall dreams when I first wake up, it is good practice.

Comment: for a "real philosopher" (i suppose;) the whole world is his "wife and kids" ...there is few time left for a "job" or a "real life"! ;) "real philosopher" (must) live "unreal life"! 

Comment: for a "normal human" (i suppose): "honor truth(death), respect lies(life)!" seems a good motto (resp- lao-tsu) ..it means: try to "catch up(+recap) the thread you are reading" as often as you can, but (in first place) be a "good": worker/father/husband/houseman/your occupation... be there (&"best"), whenever they call you! (my advice)

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.